# adding a shadow border to my wrapper

Tags: html, css, wrapper, shadow

I have a `#wrapper`, which contains all page content, and I'd like to place another div around it with a shadow border, `#shadowwrap`.  I've been staring at this stuff for way to long today, and my brain's stuck...

```
#shadowwrap {
    background:url("images/shadowborder.png") repeat-y center;
    background-color:transparent;
    max-width:1000px;
    min-width:1000px;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color:#FFF; 
    width:100%;
    max-width:980px;
    min-width:980px;
    min-height:100%!important;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

site: http://www.hcfmissoula.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your life a lot easier by just applying the shadow to the `#wrapper` element like so:

```
#wrapper {
   /* shadowborder.png should be 1000px wide (10px of shadow on either side and 
      980px of white to create the solid background colour)  */
   background: url("images/shadowborder.png") repeat-y 0 0;        

   /* The 10px of left and right padding + 980px of width will result in a 
      1000px wide #wrapper */
   padding: 0 10px;
   width: 980px;

   /* remaining CSS.  I removed min-width and max-width because they were 
      both the same value and therefore didn't do much ;) */
   min-height: 100% !important;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-bottom: -50px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: auto;
}
```